# How do I edit text in a stock photo that has a design attached to it?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I have a 'logo' that I want to edit but I'm not sure how I can edit this one section. I added my own text, i.e. "Brunettes, Rosettes", but I need the middle text to be changed from initials to a "&". The problem is there is a floral design that connects to the letters so I don't know how to manipulate it. Does anybody know how I can change that middle text? I'm using Adobe Illustrator and the file is also AI.

[image: Stock image in Illustrator]

Comment: You have to *draw* it. There's no automated method to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object you have highlighted isn't editable text, so you can't just retype the text. It's a single closed path. You can tell this because the path is highlighted in blue in your example screenshot.

To edit it, you could cut up the design and delete the r and n using a rectangle with Path Finder Minus Front, leaving the rose, leaves and stalks, then draw or type a suitable ampersand, convert it to outlines, modify the outlines to connect it to the stalks, and do a Pathfinder Union operation on all the pieces, then apply the gradient again.

A very rough example showing the process:

[image]